# XML parsing fails when a newline is in the file?

Tags: android

I always thought that newlines and whitespace in XML documents were ignored ? Is that a misconception, or is there something lacking in my code?

What happens is the following: I'm parsing an XML document which I retrieve from my server. This works fine when all content is on 1 line, but fails when the XML document is indented.

My code :

```
public class JsonTestActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Log.d("xxx", "on create started");
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.morefast.be/gethistory.php");

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());        

            String path = doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeValue() ;

            Log.d("xxx", "path is "+path);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("xxx", e.getMessage());

        }



    }



}
```

Works fine when the XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"><Document>
<GeometryCollection><LineString><coordinates>These are the coordinates</coordinates></LineString></GeometryCollection>
</Document></kml>
```

But fails when the file is (e.g.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"><Document>
<GeometryCollection>
<LineString><coordinates>These are the coordinates</coordinates></LineString></GeometryCollection>
</Document></kml>
```

All I changed in those files is adding an extra newline after "GeometryCollection"

LogCat shows

```
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.jsontest/com.mydomain.jsontest.JsonTestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:122)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at com.mydomain.jsontest.JsonTestActivity.onCreate(JsonTestActivity.java:43)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-30 20:44:48.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     ... 11 more
```

Is that expected? I'd thought that XML documents ignored whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't do Android (or even Java these days) programming, however...

---

White-space in XML *is generally not ignored* by the parser. Rather it is turned into *text nodes* (containing the white-space as content). The exact details depends on the XML parser and options 
supplied.

Could this be changing what `getFirstChild()` is doing? That is, is the first child of `GeometryCollection` a *text node* and not `LineString`? (And the first child of a *text node* is ...? **Kaboom!** Although, I can't fit this into the trace: `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`... which seems odd sitting there.)

I would suggest starting with a better selector and avoiding the manual stepping, if this is indeed the case.

Happy coding.

Comment: I expect `println needs a message` relates to `Log.d("xxx", "path is "+path);` when the `path` String is null. See the answer I posted to see if it makes sense.

Comment: @MisterSquonk but `"str" + null` is valid and results in `"str"`, which is why I question that particular exception. But yes, your answer agrees with my hypothesis ;-)

Comment: @MisterSquonk Well, mostly agrees. I am not sure how a text node can have a child node...

Comment: Good point - DOM prohibits text nodes from having children. As for the `println` exception, looking at the source for `Log.d` and a few registered Android issues still suggests the `path` String being `null` is the root of the NPE.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm still confused though, if whitespace is not ignored and turned into textnodes, then parsing XML documents becomes even more cumbersome. I think I'll stick with JSON.

Comment: @user410932 It is only cumbersome because of using the `getFirstChild` -- such a construct *doesn't exist* in JSON. So to say "XML parsing is more cumbersome" [just] based off of that is to ignore the fact that *the method used is not ideal*. [Use XPath/XQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) :) There are also libraries to use XML as a "JSON-like serialization" (e.g. only expose the ARRAY/HASH/VALUE access) as well as libraries that allow easy POJO serialization and similar.

Answer (score 1):

It should ignore whitespaces.
However, I notice you call `getFirstChild()` 3 times and <GeometryCollection> is only 2 children deep.

Comment: @pst might be right. You could check for that by calling `getFirstChild()` only once and logging the value...or checking if the next call to it will return a `null`.

Answer (score 1):

pst is correct (I think).

`getFirstChild()` returns a 'Node'. In DOM a 'Node' can be an element, attribute or (inner) text etc etc.

I think what is happening is the newline is being treated as a text Node which means the final `getFirstChild()` is landing on the `<coordinates>` Element. Using `getNodeValue()` on an Element Node will return `null`